# What is an "optimal convergence rate" ?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions that goes in $L^2$ to $f$,

$$\Vert f_n - f \Vert_{L^2} \to 0 $$

"Show that $f_n$ have an optimal convergence rate in $L^2$" What does that mean ?

Comment: It probably means something related to the way in which the particular functions $f_n$ were defined. Can you say something about that?

Comment: So we have a differential equation that depends on $n$, $f_n$ is its solution. We show that $f_n \to f$ (which is the solution of the limit differential equation) pointwise and in $L^2$, we also have $f'_n$ goes weakly to $f'$ in $L^2$.